# iOS - Create a "drag bar" to scroll UIScrollView without touching it

Tags: ios, scroll, uiscrollview, drag

I need to create a bar which has a handler. When user drags this handler the related UIScrollView (also tables and collections) scroll to the desired position. Something like the bar in the iBooks app. Do you know if there are some components on GitHub? Or how to create this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It can be made with UISlider. It is control provided by iOS.